# Is it okay if someone offers money for providing an answer?

Tags: discussion

I've seen such situations where users are so desperate to get quick solution that they often offer money to get their issue solved.

I personally feel that we must offer free solution without any expectation of monetory benefits. So, I've refused such offers everytime. But I'm interested to know if someone accepts the offer, is he breaking rules?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: NO.
Long answer: You should flag any question/answer/comment in which the OP requests or offers money.